# My Neural Network (from scratch) training, leaves it further away from target

Tags: go, machine-learning, neural-network

This is my first time ever creating a neural network, and I've decided to create it in golang, which is not typically a language used for this, however I wanted to create a good understanding of how they work from scratch with only **basic** libraries.

The goal of the program is to train a Neural Network to be able to add two numbers, 1-10, together. To do this I have created a Neural Network class called RawAI (Best name I could come up with), and given it a 1 input layer (array of size 2), 1 hidden layer (array of size 2) and 1 output layer (array of size 1).

There are 2 2D arrays for weights, one is IH (input to Hidden) [2,2] and one is HO, [2,1].

Below is the code which initiates the AI, trains it, and tests it. You will see a couple of the debugging statements I have used, and any other function which is not native to golang or its package will be shown in the following code for my RawAI class. This is called by my main function.:

```
func AdditionNeuralNetworkTest() {
    nn := NewRawAI(2, 2, 1, 1/math.Pow(10, 15))
    fmt.Printf("Weights IH Before: %v\n\nWeights HO After: %v\n", nn.WeightsIH, nn.WeightsHO)
    //Train Neural Network
    //
    for epoch := 0; epoch < 10000000; epoch++ {
        for i := 0; i <= 10; i++ {
            for j := 0; j <= 10; j++ {
                inputs := make([]float64, 2)
                targets := make([]float64, 1)
                inputs[0] = float64(i)
                inputs[1] = float64(j)
                targets[0] = float64(i) + float64(j)
                nn.Train(inputs, targets)
                if epoch%20000 == 0 && i == 5 && j == 5 {
                    fmt.Printf("[TRAINING] [EPOCH %d] %f + %f = %f TARGETS[%f]\n", epoch, inputs[0], inputs[1], nn.OutputLayer[0], targets[0])
                }

            }

        }
    }
    // Test neural network
    a := rand.Intn(10) + 1
    b := rand.Intn(10) + 1
    inputs := make([]float64, 2)
    inputs[0] = float64(a)
    inputs[1] = float64(b)
    prediction := nn.FeedForward(inputs)[0]
    fmt.Printf("%d + %d = %f\n", a, b, prediction)
    fmt.Printf("Weights IH: %v\n\nWeights HO: %v\n", nn.WeightsIH, nn.WeightsHO)

}
```

Below is all of the code in the RawAI File:

```
type RawAI struct {
    InputLayer   []float64   `json:"input_layer"`
    HiddenLayer  []float64   `json:"hidden_layer"`
    OutputLayer  []float64   `json:"output_layer"`
    WeightsIH    [][]float64 `json:"weights_ih"`
    WeightsHO    [][]float64 `json:"weights_ho"`
    LearningRate float64     `json:"learning_rate"`
}

func NewRawAI(inputSize, hiddenSize, outputSize int, learningRate float64) *RawAI {
    nn := RawAI{
        InputLayer:   make([]float64, inputSize),
        HiddenLayer:  make([]float64, hiddenSize),
        OutputLayer:  make([]float64, outputSize),
        WeightsIH:    randomMatrix(inputSize, hiddenSize),
        WeightsHO:    randomMatrix(hiddenSize, outputSize),
        LearningRate: learningRate,
    }
    return &nn
}
func (nn *RawAI) FeedForward(inputs []float64) []float64 {
    // Set input layer
    for i := 0; i < len(inputs); i++ {
        nn.InputLayer[i] = inputs[i]
    }

    // Compute hidden layer
    for i := 0; i < len(nn.HiddenLayer); i++ {
        sum := 0.0
        for j := 0; j < len(nn.InputLayer); j++ {
            sum += nn.InputLayer[j] * nn.WeightsIH[j][i]
        }
        nn.HiddenLayer[i] = sum
        if math.IsNaN(sum) {
            panic(fmt.Sprintf("Sum is NaN on Hidden Layer:\nInput Layer: %v\nHidden Layer: %v\nWeights IH: %v\n", nn.InputLayer, nn.HiddenLayer, nn.WeightsIH))
        }

    }

    // Compute output layer
    for k := 0; k < len(nn.OutputLayer); k++ {
        sum := 0.0
        for j := 0; j < len(nn.HiddenLayer); j++ {
            sum += nn.HiddenLayer[j] * nn.WeightsHO[j][k]
        }
        nn.OutputLayer[k] = sum
        if math.IsNaN(sum) {
            panic(fmt.Sprintf("Sum is NaN on Output Layer:\n Model: %v\n", nn))
        }

    }

    return nn.OutputLayer
}
func (nn *RawAI) Train(inputs []float64, targets []float64) {
    nn.FeedForward(inputs)

    // Compute output layer error
    outputErrors := make([]float64, len(targets))
    for k := 0; k < len(targets); k++ {
        outputErrors[k] = targets[k] - nn.OutputLayer[k]
    }

    // Compute hidden layer error
    hiddenErrors := make([]float64, len(nn.HiddenLayer))
    for j := 0; j < len(nn.HiddenLayer); j++ {
        errorSum := 0.0
        for k := 0; k < len(nn.OutputLayer); k++ {
            errorSum += outputErrors[k] * nn.WeightsHO[j][k]
        }
        hiddenErrors[j] = errorSum * sigmoidDerivative(nn.HiddenLayer[j])
        if math.IsInf(math.Abs(hiddenErrors[j]), 1) {
            //Find out why
            fmt.Printf("Hidden Error is Infinite:\nTargets:%v\nOutputLayer:%v\n\n", targets, nn.OutputLayer)
        }
    }

    // Update weights
    for j := 0; j < len(nn.HiddenLayer); j++ {
        for k := 0; k < len(nn.OutputLayer); k++ {
            delta := nn.LearningRate * outputErrors[k] * nn.HiddenLayer[j]
            nn.WeightsHO[j][k] += delta
        }
    }
    for i := 0; i < len(nn.InputLayer); i++ {
        for j := 0; j < len(nn.HiddenLayer); j++ {
            delta := nn.LearningRate * hiddenErrors[j] * nn.InputLayer[i]
            nn.WeightsIH[i][j] += delta
            if math.IsNaN(delta) {
                fmt.Print(fmt.Sprintf("Delta is NaN.\n Learning Rate: %f\nHidden Errors: %f\nInput: %f\n", nn.LearningRate, hiddenErrors[j], nn.InputLayer[i]))
            }
            if math.IsNaN(nn.WeightsIH[i][j]) {
                fmt.Print(fmt.Sprintf("Delta is NaN.\n Learning Rate: %f\nHidden Errors: %f\nInput: %f\n", nn.LearningRate, hiddenErrors[j], nn.InputLayer[i]))
            }
        }
    }

}
func (nn *RawAI) ExportWeights(filename string) error {
    weightsJson, err := json.Marshal(nn)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = ioutil.WriteFile(filename, weightsJson, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
func (nn *RawAI) ImportWeights(filename string) error {
    weightsJson, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = json.Unmarshal(weightsJson, nn)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

//RawAI Tools:
func randomMatrix(rows, cols int) [][]float64 {
    matrix := make([][]float64, rows)
    for i := 0; i < rows; i++ {
        matrix[i] = make([]float64, cols)
        for j := 0; j < cols; j++ {
            matrix[i][j] = 1.0
        }
    }
    return matrix
}
func sigmoid(x float64) float64 {
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-x))
}
func sigmoidDerivative(x float64) float64 {
    return x * (1.0 - x)
}

func exp(x float64) float64 {
    return 1.0 + x + (x*x)/2.0 + (x*x*x)/6.0 + (x*x*x*x)/24.0
}
```

The example of the output is this: [image: Example Output]
As you can see it slowly moves further from target and continues to do so.
After asking around, googling, and searching through this website I could not find what seemed to be my error, so I decided to ask this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using `mean-square error` and forget `-` after the differential.

So change:

```
outputErrors[k] =  (targets[k] - nn.OutputLayer[k])
```

To:

```
outputErrors[k] = -(targets[k] - nn.OutputLayer[k])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of off-target, since you wanted to do it from scratch. But if you are interested in machine learning for Go, it's worth check out [github.com/gomlx/gomlx](https://github.com/gomlx/gomlx), kind of like Jax/TensorFlow for Go.

While the matrix multiplication is done in the accelerator (XLA), you can check out there a clean (and well documented) the implementation of the other parts you probably will want to learn about, like the various optimizers (Adam in particular), normalization (layer and batch), dropout, losses, metrics and related things. They play a large role in the success of NN.

There is also a tutorial and some examples.